# Applying to position with multiple offices

Tags: job-search

I am applying to a position with openings in multiple offices of a large company. I am flexible and willing to work at any of them. Is there a standard on which address I should put on the cover letter?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about regulations, agreements or procedures that are **company-specific** and don't have universally applicable answers.

Comment: Presumably the application form or job advertisement gives an address to send it to?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard on which address I should put on the cover letter?

I know of no such standard.

Often, such jobs have a corporate office that handles hiring for multiple locations. If that's the case, your cover letter and application materials should go to this home office, and you can indicate your willingness to work at any location.

If that's not the case, and the company conducts hiring at each individual location, you should probably apply separately to each location where you could work. Separate applications, and separate cover letters.